# loop cut not stopping my bevel

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I am trying to bevel this edge but I want the bevel to stop at the loop cut that I made, however the bevel just goes straight through the loop cut, how do I make it stop at the loop cut? As you can see the bevel on the right stopped but when I bevel the left side it doesn't stop.

ps- I am trying to get it to stop at the edge loop because I want the bevel to be "flatter" instead of having an even distribution

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bevel looks like this:
[image]

And you want it to stop on the closest edge, you need to check this option called Clamp overlap, that will lock it as soon as it arrives to the closest edge, at this moment going with Width to higher number does nothing at all:

[image]

Also, to control the curve and flattnes of bevel you need to change **Shape** value in that pop up menu, don't forget to apply scale before beveling